# Silex Firewall setup for admin path

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, silex

i need to setup my silex firewall like:

```
www.mysite.com/* => access to all users
www.mysite.com/admin/* => access to only logged in users
```

i use this set up but it does not work as expected:

```
$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
            'security.firewalls' => array(
                'secure' => [
                    'pattern' => '^/.*$',
                    'anonymous' => true, 
                    'form' => array(
                        'login_path' => '/admin/login',
                        'check_path' => '/admin/auth'
                    ),
                    'logout' => array(
                        'logout_path' => '/admin/logout'
                    ),
                    'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
                        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler($app['db']);
                    }),
                ]
            ),
            'security.access_rules' => array(
                array('^/admin$', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            )

        ));
```

Any help?
Many Thanks!! ;-)

Comment: can you elaborate on "does not work as expected"

Comment: Also add monolog provider and enable debug (```$app['debug'] = true```), then check your logs. The security component does yell lots of information when logging is enabled. Oh, and yes you should really elaborate more on "does not work as expected" :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
'users' => $app->share(function() use ($app) {
     return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler($app['db']);
 }),
```

The above function needs to return an object which implements

> Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface

Check here for custom user provider [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-a-custom-user-provider)

It may also be appropriate to move login_path outside the secured area. Another way of configuring would be:

```
  $app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'secure' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/admin/',
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/admin/auth'),
    'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
         return new MyUserProvider($app['db']); 
     }),
    ),
  ),
);
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
array('^/admin', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
);
```

Make sure you register doctrine dbal.